# Is it possible to install a local plugin as a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a directory called 'xmonroe' in the `vendor/plugins` folder of my Rails app.

It doesn't have a gemspec, only various rake files.

Would it be possible to install this as a gem or does this require a lot of tinkering?

The reason I am considering this is because when I run the `xmonroe_install` script as described in the readme for the plugin as follows:

```
script/generate xmonroe_install
```

It produces the output:

```
Missing these required gems:
  xmonroe
```

But the gem is not available as an installable gem from the usual places.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a gemspec it is impossible to install.

You could use a tool like `jeweler` to create one, then `rake install` should install the local gem.